# (Python) How can I add a char into a string, if only there is a number behind it

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, char, numbers

How can I add '*' into a string, behind a specific `char`, if there is a number symbol after that `char`?

Here's my code that I tried, but doesn't work:

```
def timesAdd(string, char):
    nString = None;
    if char in string:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if string[i] == char:
                if string[i-1].isdigit():
                    nString += '*' + char;         
                else:
                    nString += char;
            else:
                nString += string[i];
    return nString;
```

What I tried to do is:

1. Scan each symbol of the string to see if it equals `char`
2. If `i` in string equals `char`, go back one, and see if it's a number.
3. If it's a number, add '*' before `char`, else just add `char` to the buffer
4. When done, return buffer.

Why did it not work, and how can I improve it?

*Side note, another idea that I didn't try is to make a `array of chars`, and see if `string[i]` equals one of the symbols in the `array of chars` (Example of the `array`: "1234567890").*

Comment: FWIW, this would be trivial using a [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: Please clarify your requirement by showing sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

deceze is right.This code should solve your problem.

```py
import re


def timesAdd(string, char):
    pattern = r"(?<=\d)(%s)" % char
    replacement = "*" + char
    return re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons this did not work:

1. You initialize `nString` to `None`. When you try to append a character to `nString` using the `+=` operator, it will throw an error.
2. You loop through `range(len(string))`. This will throw an error for the first iteration, because when your loop variable `i = 0`, `string[i - 1]` will not exist.

To fix these you will need to (1) initialize `nString` to a string (2) start your loop at `i = 1`

Here is the working code:

```
def timesAdd(string, char):
    if char not in string:
        return None
    
    nString = string[0]

    for i in range(1, len(string)):
        if string[i] == char and string[i-1].isdigit():
            nString += '*' 
        nString += string[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without *re* which also gives a marginally faster implementation:

```
def timesAdd(string, char):
    if string:
        result = [prev := string[0]]
        for c in string[1:]:
            if c == char and prev.isdecimal():
                result.append('*')
            result.append(prev := c)
        return ''.join(result)
    return string
```